# Text Editing with NSCollectionView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextfield, nscollectionview

I've been banging my head against the wall (Cocoa) for about a week with this problem and wanted to get some advice if possible.

I'm trying to provide a list of NSTextFields to the user representing a list of features – letting them add additional textfields using an 'Add' button. This is part of a bigger form and the user should just be able to tab through the whole form (including the list)

I implemented the above using an NSCollectionView which pretty much worked except tabbing seemed to intermittently stop working in the NSCollectionView for reasons I can not figure out. You'll be hitting tab, cycling through normally when all of a sudden the collection view is skipped altogether, or sometimes if you're in a specific text field in the collection view hitting tab will just highlight the text but will never jump to the next field without mouse clicking outside the collection view. I was wondering if anyone had experienced this before... or has any advice for debugging something like this? I've attempted logging what the nextResponder is every time a control becomes the responder and there doesn't seem to be any pattern explaining why tabbing just stops working suddenly and then begins again.

There are 3 TabViews with a collection view in each. I have been wondering if that may be causing an issue?

Thanks for any help anyone can provide.

Answer (score 1):

OK, after all this time I may have solved this (Tentatively anyway... I haven't seen any problems on numerous run-throughs and it usually occurs at least once every time before)

Turning on Auto Recalculates View Loop on the Main Window seems to have resolved whatever was happening. I have to admit I don't completely understand why, except that maybe because of the tab views and collections views the key loop needs to be recalculated to keep everything in sync. I'm thinking I need to do more research into exactly how the key loops work...